# ui-router $stateParams not loading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a weird issue with my routing states. For example, my state:

```
.state("systemInformation", {
  url: '/system_info/:system',
  views: {
    "content@app": {
     controller : 'SystemInformationController',
     templateUrl : 'pages/systemInformation.html',
     params: {
      system : null
     }
    }
  }
})
```

This works fine, it goes to the page, it loads the controller, and it has access to the parent controller (also loading). I'm using a `ui-view` in my index.html page, so I know that can't be the issue because it's loading 4 other controllers fine.

But when I add this state:

```
.state("systemRegistration", {
  url: '/system_reg/:system*/:survey_page*',
  views: {
    "content@app": {
     controller : 'SystemRegistrationController',
     templateUrl : 'pages/systemRegistration.html',
     params: {
      system : null,
      survey_page : null
     }
    }
  }
})
```

All it does is load the string `/#/system_reg/new_system/Basic%20System%20Information` into my URL, and the `$stateProvider` does nothing. I've triple checked for typos, and with `$routeProvider` I had no issues with controller routing.

Is there something I'm not seeing here? There's no errors because the controller isn't running (it's loaded, and it's the same format as the other states), and the template path IS correct as well, so that's not the reason either.

Here is the HTML links:

```
<li><a href="#/system_reg/new_system/Basic System Information" ng-click="clearRegSurvey()">Register a System</a></li>

<li><a href="#/system_search">Find a System</a></li>
```

Note: the system search also has a state route, and works, even without a ui-sref. This is why I'm confused. Also, `ui-sref` does not work for the sys reg page.

Comment: show us your html code, i mean ui-sref="...."

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue in plunker?

Comment: Unfortunately the effort to make a plunker would be huge for me. Can't make a working example. i've edited in the links though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Turns out the stateProvider doesn't like the wildcard stars (*) in the url route. I'm not sure why, because the initial is fine, but I guess with more than one route param you can't use the wildcard symbols.

```
url: '/system_reg/:system/:survey_page',
```

And now it works.